# How to find the new coordinates for a vector when there is a shift in a new system of coordinates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

The figure from below shows two systems of cartesian coordinates. On ($x,y$) vector $\vec{A}$ is expressed as $\vec{A}=5\hat{i}+4\hat{j}$. Find the vector $\sqrt{2}\vec{A}$ on the system $x',y'$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&9\hat{i'}+\hat{j'}\\
2.&\hat{i'}+9\hat{j'}\\
3.&-9\hat{i'}+\hat{j'}\\
4.&9\hat{i'}-\hat{j'}\\
5.&\hat{i'}-9\hat{j'}\\
\end{array}$

Does it exist a way to solve this problem visually or with least use of algebra?. The only thing which I could spot for the vector given is that the angle for the vector is:

$\tan\omega=\frac{4}{5}$

therefore $\omega=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)$

This angle is not very known. How exactly can I relate it with the tilt in the new system of coordinates?. What exactly is what should I do?.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this very easily using some basic vectors. Observe-
$$x'=\frac {\hat i+\hat j}{\sqrt 2}\;,\;\;\; y'=\frac {\hat i-\hat j}{\sqrt 2}$$
Solving for $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ gives us the following-
$$\hat i=\frac {x'+y'}{\sqrt 2}\;,\;\;\; \hat j=\frac {x'-y'}{\sqrt 2}$$
Substituting this in $\vec A=5\hat i+4\hat j$ gives us the following -
$$\vec A=\frac 9{\sqrt2} x'+\frac 1{\sqrt2} y'$$
$$\sqrt 2\vec A=9x'+y'$$